# how to get the value of the parameter with $@ in busybox shell

Tags: bash, shell, posix, busybox, ash

In a busybox shell script test.sh (not bash), if I pass 4 paramters into it, how can I get the value from each of them directly. for example

```
#!/bin/sh

args=("$@")
param3=${args[2]}  #I want to get the value of the parameter 3, it works in bash
                   #but it does not work in busybox shell
```

If I run the script like this:

```
$test.sh 1 2 "3 4" 5
```

the purpose is that I want to get the NO3 string "3 4" directly in the script. How can I do it in the busybox shell

Comment: POSIX shell doesn't have arrays. I'll bet Busybox shell doesn't have them.

Comment: Did you try `"$3"`?

Answer (score 1):

Busybox shell is a simple, POSIX-compliant shell (specifically, [`ash`](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/ash/), Almquist Shell). POSIX shell doesn't require arrays, and I'll bet `ash` doesn't have them.

But you don't need an array for script parameters, they're automatically put into variables `$1`, `$2`, etc. So you just need:

```
param3=$3
```

Make sure when you use `$param3` that you put it in double quotes, so you don't run into problems due to the space (unless you want them split into separate arguments).

```
some_other_command "$param3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not part of the POSIX specification. So simply use `param3="$3"`. No need to use arrays (applies also for `bash`). More about positional parameters [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/chap2.html#tag_001_005_001).